# yii framework populate the values in textarea

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I need to populate the value in textarea.

For text field i used the following command `$form->textField($model,'phone',array('value'=>$savedvalues['varPhone']))`

It works fine. But for textarea the 'value' parameter is not supported.

Here where i  have to display my value parameter

```
$form->textArea($model, 'corporateaddress', array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50))
```

Comment: do you have to use the $savedValues array for textArea? and not a default value? do you not want a default value, but only some helper text? for default value @mazzucci solution will work

Comment: yes i want to use the $savedValues array for textArea. I do not need the default value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this, if you absolutely have to use `$savedvalues` array:

```
$model->corporateaddress=$savedvalues['varCorporateAddress'];
$form->textArea($model, 'corporateaddress', array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50));
```

Comment: try this it should work out, just adding to what mazzucci already said

Answer (score 1):

The values of the textarea will be set to `$model->corporateaddress`.
You could set in your model a default value if that is the case.

I found a similar question here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10454-textarea-set-default-text/